# Function does not Print the while line in a file in C

Tags: c, string, file, fgets

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my code. I basically have a file and each line contains a fortune. I am supposed to get the day of birth from the user and give their zodiac sign and fortune from there.

I have a file that contains all the fortunes. This is my work so far:

```
    //gets position in the array filled with the size of bytes per line
    int ok = 0;
    i = 0;
    j = d.zodiac;

    while(ok == 0 && i < arrSize){
        if(j == zodiacMarker[i]){
            zodiacMarker[i] = -1;
            ok = 1;
        }
        i++;
    }

    locationMark = i - 1;
    printf("\nLocation Mark: %i", locationMark);

    //get the size of the file to get to the specific line in the file
    int finalSize = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < locationMark; i++){
        finalSize += byteSize[i];
    }

    //goes to the position
    fseek(fp, finalSize+2, SEEK_SET);

    printf("\nFinal Size: %i\n", finalSize);
    printf("Where now: %i\n", ftell(fp));
    printf("Size: %i\n", byteSize[locationMark+1]);
    printf("fgets part : %i\n", byteSize[locationMark]+1);

    char arr[byteSize[locationMark+1]];

    //gets the string in that line
    fgets(arr, byteSize[locationMark]+1, fp);

    printf("%s", arr);
```

Another thing for the logic in getting the size of each line. I want to get the size of each line and add them to get to the specific location I want to be in the line.

```
int charCount( FILE *const fp ){

    char c;
    int count = 0;

    for( ;; ){
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if( c == EOF || c == '\n' )
            break;
        ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Heres my output:

```
Month:4
Day: 8
Aries:
Location Mark: 2
Final Size: 106
Where now: 108
Size: 33
fgets part : 61
Thinking you know something is a sure way to blind yourself.
```

```
Month:3
Day: 6
Pisces:
Location Mark: 1
Final Size: 64
Where now: 66
Size: 60
fgets part : 43
ssumption is the mother of all screw-ups.
```

As you can see, it gets all wonky. I dont know why. Please send help and if you have better suggestions on how to go about this problem, please do share. Much appreciated!

Comment: Just use `fgets` in a loop to count/skip lines. It is pretty fast.

Comment: What is `byteSize` and were is it filled?

Comment: You also must process the file as binary for this to work, so `"rb"`

Comment: The code you show is incomplete. Difficult to help.

Comment: What is the while line? You do not have the word "while" in a `printf` call, nor a `printf` call in the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I forgot to take into account the multiple `\n` from each line. So I went for this

`fseek(fp, finalSize + locationMark, SEEK_SET);`